# Improve performance on top 1 query

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, cross-apply

I am running a batch of statements, and 100% of the relative time in used by this query:

```
select c.*,q.dbupddate
  into #c
  from 
   customer c
   cross apply
   (
    select top 1 code,transferred,dbupddate
    from transfer_customer_connect_log l
    where l.code=c.code
    order by dbupddate desc
   )q
  where q.transferred=0
```

with this plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syq811nJm

This query is meant to transfer rows from one database (app_connect) to another (app). In the table transfer_customer_connect_log, records with transferred=1 are already processed and must be ignored. Furthermore, from the remaining rows with transferred=0, some (customer) codes might exist multiple times in the table, with different (dbupd)dates, in which case I must only consider the most recent.

I saw from the plan that the `sort by dbupddate`, to make the top 1 part, takes 97% of the time. So, I added a pk clustered index on (dbupddate,code). Interestingly enough, nothing changed! Wouldn't an index make sorting unnecessary?

One alternative approach would be, instead of making the top 1 most recent check every time, to "save" its results on every row insertion by marking the "old" rows (transferred=0 but not top 1 recent) with a flag, and then using that flag in a `where` to exclude it from future considerations.

Is that way of thinking solid? What else could I do to improve on this, based on the functionality I described?

Comment: Your index should be first by code, then by dbupddate, since you are filtering by the customer code first, then getting the date. You can also try with  group by with MAX().

Comment: ezlo that worked. I might try to improve it still, but now it has an index seek for code and top n takes 0 time :)

Answer (score 0):

using row_number()

```
select * 
from ( select c.*, l.dbupddate, l.transferred 
            , row_number() over (PARTITION BY l.code ORDER BY l.dbupddate desc) as rn
        from customer c
        join transfer_customer_connect_log l
          on l.code = c.code 
     ) t
where t.rn = 1
  and t.transferred = 0
```